# C Files in iOS App

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

What happens if I make an app with some C files? Will apple reject it? I want to embed GCC into my app to compile user input.

Would that be possible?

Comment: I don't know about C files, but I doubt that they would allow an embedded GCC compiler.

Comment: Using C code in your app is perfectly normal. Embedding gcc and compiling code on the device is something completely different. I suggest you amend your question and title.

Comment: Yea, an app with an embedded compiler will be rejected outright.

Comment: @Perception if they follow their own guidelines it should permit a compiler, you just wouldn't be able to do anything very useful with it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Apple's rejection policies. See also: [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to compile code that you obtain from elsewhere, *on the device*, then that is explicitly forbidden by the contract you sign with Apple (I know it's a pain, but I highly recommend reading it).

Comment: I'll just use ideone.com or some compiler server with an API. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Section **2.7** and **2.8** of the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) covers this

**2.7**
Apps that download code in any way or form will be rejected

**2.8**
Apps that install or launch other executable code will be rejected

Essentially it looks like you may be able embed GCC in your app but it would be useless. You would only be allowed to compile local code and not execute it.

Comment: So I can't run anything and check its output? I want the user to enter some code, then I just check its stdout output.

Comment: Nope, and since it would be essentially useless seems like it would be enough for Apple to reject the app. Also based on your other comment, ideone.com or something similar is what other apps do that compile and test code.

Answer (score 0):

Simon's comment above is correct.  Embedding GCC in your app would likely be viewed as a violation of Apple's TOS ( see Section 3.3 in the SDK agreement ).

However.  Apple has been lenient in allowing the use of languages like Lua on iOS devices - see [Codify](http://twolivesleft.com/Codea/) as an example.  You *may* be allowed to parse and interpret C-files in an iOS app so long as you are not generating machine code to be executed out of process; that is to say, you effectively write a C-ish interpreter.  Whether or not this is an enjoyable exercise for you depends entirely on your tastes; whether or not Apple accepts this distinction depends entirely on their whims.